# Javascript Nested Form Railcasts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi i am trying to do the railcasts nested form, part 1 and part 2. It seem i am having several issues and I don't understand why.

```
Question 1: The add and remove links don't works, they show up but don't actually execute anything
Question 2: I get the following error code and don't understand why? The error is regarding the f.error_messages is not recognized
Question 3: When trying to create a surveys i get: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: answer
```

Thank you here my code similar to the railcasts 196,197

model question

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
  attr_accessible :content, :question_id, :name, :answers_attributes
  has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers , :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

model answer

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  attr_accessible :content, :question_id
end
```

model surveys

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions , :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessible :name, :questions_attributes
end
```

views
form

```
<%= form_for(@survey) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Question", f, :questions %></p>
  <%= f.fields_for :questions do |bf|%>
    <% render 'question_fields', :f => bf %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

question_fields

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :content, "Question" %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :content, :rows=> 3 %>
  <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %>
</p>
<p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Answer", f, :answers %></p>
<%= f.fields_for :answer do |form| %>
  <%= render 'answer_fields', :f => form %>
<% end %>
```

answer_fields

```
<p class="fields">
  <%= f.label :content, "Answer" %>
  <%= f.text_field :content %>
  <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %>
</p>
```

controller

javascript
application.js

```
function remove_fields(link) {
  $(link).previous("input[type=hidden]").value = "1";
  $(link).up(".fields").hide();
}

function add_fields(link, association, content) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
  $(link).up().insert({
    before: content.replace(regexp, new_id)
  });
}
```

application_jquery.js

```
function remove_fields(link) {
  $(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
  $(link).closest(".fields").hide();
}

function add_fields(link, association, content) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
  $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Here the link to the tutorial
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

And the route not sure what you mean.

```
Surveysays::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :surveys
end
```

Comment: Where are your routes? You should also have nested routes to support the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` stuff. Also, I believe I know which episodes you're referring to, but can you post the links to the episodes you're following?

Comment: Accepts_nested_attributes_for is in my models, isn't where it should be?

Comment: Never mind, sorry. I re-read the code, and I think I may be wrong about the nested routes.

Comment: No problem, do u know what is wrong with my code? Maybe i didn't call the application_jquery code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question1: Those functions are not being called when you press the button.  In the railscast he adds the link_to_remove and link_to_add to the application helper.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_remove_fields(name, f)
    f.hidden_field(:_destroy) + link_to_function(name, "remove_fields(this)")
  end

 def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
   new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
   fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}")    do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
   end
    link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")")
  end
end
```

Question 2: Not sure, but it might clear up with some of the other fixes

Question 3: You have a type here:

```
<%= f.fields_for :answer do |form| %>
  <%= render 'answer_fields', :f => form %>
<% end %>
```

Should be

```
<%= f.fields_for :answers do |form| %>
  <%= render 'answer_fields', :f => form %>
<% end %>
```

It's answers because you have a has_many relations ship. The attribute answer doesn't exist and is also whitelisted by default.  That's why you get mass assignment errors.

Also there is a simpler version of this in his revised episode:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Comment: Hmm so should i take from the revised or your update would work?

Comment: Either should work.  The revised episode just cleans things up a bit, but work on the same concepts.  But yeah the non-revised version works.  You just had a couple of typos and no way to call your javascript functions.  The other problem you might have is that you have defined both javascript functions twice.  You should only have to define them once.

Comment: It depends on whether you're using jquery or prototype.  If you are using rails 3.1 or 3.2, you are using jquery by default.  The code in your application_jquery.js is the correct code for that.